# Who was the German philosopher who said that 'German' language is superior?

Tags: language

I can't remember exactly where I read it, but I think in a Chomsky's essay, book, or probably a video and remember saying something about a German philosopher who claimed that German language is superior in some sort of way.

Does anyone know who was the philosopher?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [Hamann](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Georg_Hamann)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

I think both Hegel and Heidegger expressed this view.

Ironically though, many German Kant scholars nowadays prefer English translation of Kant's tomes.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!